# Fragment is invisible but its views could be clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to enable user to go to a new `Fragment` when a list item is clicked. That's OK. I created an interface which allows me to handle click events from my *FragmentA.java* class. *FragmentA* is attached to my activity when activity started. my activity extends `FragmentActivity`.

In my activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInsantaceState){
  //...
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FragmentA.newInstance(param1, param2)).commit();
}
```

And then in FragmentA.java, i set that to my RecyclerView Adapter as click handler. I use add() method instead of replace() method to change the fragment, because i want to save the FragmentA's state (like RecyclerView position etc.) when FragmentB is attached.

```
private void setListeners(){
  mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
}
    
private ItemListAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener = new ItemListAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClicked(View v, ItemModel item) {
                
  FragmentManager manager =((FragmentActivity)mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager();
            
  manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.post_activity_layout_container, FragmentB.newInstance(item, param2, param3)).addToBackStack("comment").commit();
                
}
};
```

HERE IS THE ISSUE : In this case, FragmentA is running but invisible, while user sees FragmentB. User can reach views of FragmentA, and that cause problems. I wanna save the last state of FragmentA but user should not click on views of FragmentA from FragmentB. How to handle that issue? Is there a better practice to accomplish saving the last state?

**EDIT**
FragmentA contains some sorting, filtering. When i use replace() method, all filters that user set is invalidated, and also RecyclerView position became 0. Imagine that user is looking at (for example) 33. item in the list, clicks on it, FragmentB is attached, then go back to FragmentA. I want user to continue from 33. item, don't want user to try to find for where he was.

Comment: Try Using ViewPager.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I wanna save the last state of FragmentA" exactly, but, AFAIK, the fact that you replace Fragments in a container doesn't mean they lose state. For example, you can still click on back button and this will revert the transaction, bringing the previous Fragment from the back-stack.

Edit: the effects that you observe are most probably caused by the destruction and re-creation of Fragment's View hierarchy. There are couple of approaches around it. The first one would be to store UIs state and restore it after re-initialization of the Fragment. Unfortunately, it might be tricky with RecyclerView position (you can google it). Another simpler approach (which is a hack) is to create the root View in `onCreateView` only once, keep a reference to it inside Fragment and return the same View on subsequent calls to `onCreateView`. If you decide to use the later approach, be careful because you'll be using Fragments not exactly the way there were intended to use.

Not directly related to your question, but I absolutely recommend avoiding manual Fragments management. It'll be too painful. You can use the official Navigation Component, or, alternatively, a simpler solution like FragNav library. I wrote [this post](https://www.techyourchance.com/fragment-navigation-android-fragnav-library/) about the later and it might help you.

Comment: As suggested by @Vasiliy you can use Navigation Components. Or, you can refer [this bog post](https://medium.com/@bherbst/saving-fragment-state-yourself-522c3bca78c7).

Comment: Vasiliy, i have edited the question. I have tried to explaint what i meant by "I wanna save the last state of FragmentA".